# How do I create Angular2 project with NodeJs interaction and Unit Test integration?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, setup-project

I am supposed to start an angular2 project which will get data from REST calls using NodeJS. This project will scale up to a 30+ webpages and 100+ components in future. There will be 8+ members working on each part separately. In near future, this project will be part of Continuout integration system too. I am not sure what should my initial project look like. What are the basic files required. What should my package.json and Index.html look like? Please help me.

I referred to Angular2-Node project on GIT, which has below folder structure:

[image: Angular2-Node project Folder Structure]

Here, "assets" folder contains Angular2 code (UI), bin/www is the Launch file. Basically, I don't have a starting point. All tutorials or Youtube videos that I referred to so far start from as simple as Hello World program but do not scale up to that level. Please provide some links or comments as my starting point for a large scale Angular2 application.

Comment: If your application is large, then the best method is to separate the client application (files) from server application.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion on the folder structure for the client side? Any reference links to define publishing and UT test integration for client is also fine.